# How can I speed my css and js load speed on Django

Tags: javascript, css, django, web-development-server

I have you finished my first real project and I laughed it. However, the loading speed of the CSS and js takes some seconds. Both files are hosted on AWS, however, I do not think that is the reason for the speed problem. The thing is that the files are like 3MB I do not know if that is too much, I tried to minify them, but still, it takes some time. By the way, you should know that I bought my HTML templates, rich means that the CSS was not written by me. Any recommendations, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sometimes slow loading can be due to the clients computer/device. without knowing how those 3MB files are being used it is very hard to help you.

Comment: How are the files served from AWS? Enabling gzip compression may help

Comment: take a look of django-compressor https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor